# How can I avoid the change in background image for an application while it runs in emulator/device?

Tags: android

When I run my applictaion in an emulator/device, automatically one drawable image other than default image I used, comes for my application as background. How can I avoid it?

Comment: Agree with Christopher, it's question is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what you are asking.

But if you want to set a custom background for your application, you can use an [Android theme](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) to set a `Drawable` for every screen in your app.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application ... android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme" />
```

res/values/themes.xml:

```
<resources>
  <style name="MyAppTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/custom_background</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```